# how can i send both login and actual request data in a single curl command

Tags: session, curl, session-cookies

this question is related to CURL command.
I want to post a request to one server, this request has some data to be added in body. and before that i have to login to that server again i have to add username and password in body.

Can i send both request in one time, LOGIN and 
once if you get the cookie, request the same server with second request using receiving cookies.

how can i send two requests data in single curl command? i.e both login and  also have message body.

please let me know if curl has any options to do that.

Thanks
Devendar

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! You just separate the first URL + data options with the `--next` command line option. Like this:

```
$ curl [URL1] -d "send this to first URL"
  --next
  [URL2] -d "send this to second URL"
```

You can use any number of --next.

(those are split in multiple lines here for readability, they should all be written on the same line)

Comment: But are these sequential,  I mean.
My requirements are like this:
step 1: curl -v -k --data "credential_0=xxx&credential_1=xyz&destination=/api/ext/softwareDevice.json" https://device.xyz.com/LOGIN
step2: we would get response – you will get cookie details, which will be added to second post request
step 3:curl -v --cookie "session=<session_details>" --data 'json=some JSON encoded data' -k https://device.xyz.com/api/ext/softwareDevice.json

Can we send both step1 and step3 in one shot?

Thanks
Devendar

Comment: If you need to pass in data to one of the URLs that you don't know at the time you POST to the first URL, then you cannot do it with a single curl command line. (But also, the absolute requirement to do it with a single command line should be rare.)